# Compactly supported form on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\omega$ be a compactly supported smooth $n$-form on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Show that there exists a compactly supported smooth $(n-1)$-form $\eta$
with $\omega=d\eta$ if and only if 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\omega=0.
$$
One direction is a straightforward implication of Stokes Theorem,
how can I prove the other direction without using deRham Theorem?

Comment: What *are* you willing to grant? Are we allowed to know that $H^{n-1}_{\text{deRham}}(S^{n-1})\cong\Bbb R$?

Comment: I am willing to grant things about cohomology, but not cohomology with compact support ( to make it non-trivial)

Comment: I believe I can give an argument by using spherical coordinates, but you'll find a thorough treatment of your question in Bott/Tu, of course.